# Getting Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent. in HTML5 drag & drop

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in HTML5 and i am trying to implement drag & drop feature of it
    I have two columns and want to drag and drop the content from & to these columns.These two are static column

```
    <span class="columnWidth" id="toDo">
          <div class ="columnHeader">To Do</div>
          <div class ="columnContent" 
               ondragenter ="return  dragDrop.dragEnter(event)" 
               ondrop="return dragDrop.drop(event)"
               ondragover="dragDrop.dropOver(event)"></div>
      </span>

      <span class="columnWidth">
            <div class ="columnHeader">Progress</div>
            <div class ="columnContent" 
                 ondragenter ="dragDrop.dragEnter(event)"
                 ondrop="dragDrop.drop(event)"
                 ondragover="dragDrop.dropOver(event)"></div>
       </span>
```

The draggable elements are dynamically created using javascript as follows

```
document.getElementById("toDo").getElementsByClassName('columnContent')  [0].appendChild(taskDefination);
taskDefination.addEventListener('dragstart', dragDrop.dragStart, false);
taskDefination.addEventListener('dragend', dragDrop.dragEnd, false);
```

I am including the drag & drop javascript code in a  separate javascript file.

```
var dragDrop = (function(){
    var _createDropZone = function(){

        }

    var _dragStart =function(event){
        console.log("Method Executing:dragDrop.dragStart");
        event.target.id="currentElement";
        var x=event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html',event.target.id);

    }   

    var _dragEnd = function(event){
        console.log("Method Executing:dragDrop.dragEnd")

        }   

    var _dragEnter = function(){
        console.log("Dragged dropped");
        event.preventDefault();
   return true;

        }

    var _drop=function(event){
        console.log("Method Executing :dragDrop.drop")
        event.preventDefault();
        }       

    var _dropOver = function(event){
        console.log("Method Executing:dragDrop.dropOver");
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target);
        event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(event.dataTransfer.getData('text/html')));
        y.id="";

        }   
    return{
        createDropZone:_createDropZone,
        dragStart:_dragStart,
        dragEnter:_dragEnter,
        dragEnd:_dragEnd,
        drop:_drop,
        dropOver:_dropOver
        }


    })()
```

Though the drag & drop is working but I can see an error in console as[image: Error from Console].
Secondly the console.log is suppose to give the target where the element is dropping, instead it is showing the draggable element.I also understand that I am trying to append a string but appendChild will append a node. I was referring to this http://www.sitepoint.com/a-drag-and-drop-planning-board-with-html5/.

A snapshot of draggable elements before beign dragged is

### [image: Before Dragging]

After dragging

### [image: After Dragging]

Any help to resolve this problem will be truly appreciable.Thanks!

Comment: You haven't shown us where you're setting up the events.

Comment: @JLRishe , have edited the post

Comment: Where are you setting up the dropOver event? That's the one that matters here.

Comment: @JLRishe you can refer to _dropOver event in the javascript snapshot

Comment: You're trying to grab the element when it is being dragged over a possible drop target, instead of when the user actually drops it (e.g. by releasing the mouse button, which fires the `drop` event). The `dragover` event should rather be used to indicate that a drop is possible. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#dndevents